# WPF- Resize window as per resolution when moved from one monitor to another(Dual monitor system)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, resize

Currently, I am trying to resize window as per screen resolution.
consider First monitor resolution-1366x768
Second monitor resolution- 1920x1080.

Assume my window size is covering 60% of first monitor resolution.
When this window is dragged from first monitor to second, I want to resize window as per second monitor resolution.

Is there any events or methods which I can use to implement this.

Comment: Usually you don't need to implement it on your own. I would recommend to learn about Per-Monitor DPI such as https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/PerMonitorDPI

Answer (score 0):

and you can use `DpiChanged` Event, the event is invoked when you move the window to a display with a different resolution.

Event args contain
`e.DeviceDpiOld` and `e.DeviceDpiNew`

That you can use to calculate how much you want to resize your window
Or you might want to use `e.SuggestedRectangle`to get a suggestion from the OS for a new size.

If you wanted to get the resolution of the current display, Use

```
Screen.GetBounds(this).Height;
Screen.GetBounds(this).width;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DarkDuck. I had tried  with DPI Changed Event. But Windows does not invoke this event when window is moved across monitor even with different resolution. I have implemented this using OnLocationChanged event. I am reading owner display name  and if it is changed then using updated height and width.